# Fail to drop or rename table after imported data

Tags: drop

Screenshot

[image: 1]

Hello, I cannot rename or remove the table after imported the data :(

What I have tried:

RENAME TABLE 'collections.csv' to 'collections'

DROP TABLE 'collections.csv'

I tried another table which is doing fine.

Answer (score 0):

After restarting the docker, I reran the command, which worked this time. Not sure if it is a bug